# How can I remove an element's class without ID selector - with vanilla JavaScript (no jquery)?

Tags: javascript, css, tampermonkey

First of all I've to say that I'd like to use this code in "tampermonkey";
There is a code like this:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab-content-download" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-download">
   <div class="d-none d-js-block">
       <p>...some text...</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

(I also have to mention that I have disabled Chrome Javascript in this site.)
1. Is it possible to use tampermonkey when chrome javascript is disabled?

2.How Can I remove "**d-none**" class only?

Comment: why not using CSS to reverse the CSS inside `d-none`. I am pretty it's adding `display:none` so make it `display:block`

Comment: _“How Can I remove "d-none" class only?”_ - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all the elements by class, select the first one (in this example), go to his parent and remove the element you found

Note: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements, even if only 1 element was found.

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("d-none")[0];
el.parentElement.remove(el);
```

```html
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab-content-download" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-download">
   <div class="d-none d-js-block">
       <p>...some text...</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you want to remove the class and not the element:

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("d-none")[0];
el.classList.remove("d-none");
```

```html
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab-content-download" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-download">
   <div class="d-none d-js-block">
       <p>...some text...</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- `getElementsByClassName` Find the first instance of class.
- Remove element using DOM element [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("d-none")[0].classList.remove("d-none");
```

```html
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab-content-download" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-download">
  <div class="d-none d-js-block">
    <p>...some text...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```